# load array from TextView

Tags: java, android, arrays

Is it possible to get array value from a `TextView`? In my android project I need to get value of array string from a TextView

```
final String[] amountArray = {"100$","575$","50$","70$","60$"}
(TextView) textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

This above code I write currently. I can't understand what to do now?

I want like below

```
  amountArray = textView.getText().toString();
```

but I know it will not work, because the value of TextView is String, and `amountArray` is a array string.

So, how can i convert the value of TextView to a array string and asign it to amountArray.

*The value of TextView is also: `{"100$","575$","50$","70$","60$"}`

Comment: `getText().toString()` will return you a `String` i.e "{"100$","575$","50$","70$","60$"}".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String data = textView.getText().toString();
data = data.replace("{","").replace("}","");//Remove { and }
String[] amountArray = data.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

you can split and parse the string `{"100$","575$","50$","70$","60$"}`

to get only the values `"100$","575$","50$","70$","60$"`

you could replace all the `"` and `$` symbols and split to `,`

the result will produce an array holding the [100, 575, 50, 70, 60] but those all as String.